# Crontab restart supervisor python instance?

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron, supervisord, apscheduler

I'm facing a very weird problem while using crontab to restart a supervisor python instance.
    Here is the details:

1. A very simple Python script which contain some schedule job (apscheduler)
2. The script need to be watched in supervisor, so I made some configuration, and it runs well so far.
3. A new requirement need to reset the script everyday at noon. So I setup a sudo crontab job to restart the supervisor instance by using

   ```
   01 12 * * * sudo /usr/bin/supervisorctl restart {instance name}
   ```
4. Everything seems fine, I have checked the running time of the instance everyday, it shows that the instance has been restarted correctly.
5. Then I realized that, after the instance has been restart automatically, the script was not even fired.
6. BUT, if I use the restart link in the supervisor console, the script restart & works perfect

Comment: Sorry for the text format, I'm post on my phone.

Comment: Does the cron job belong to the root user (By running `sudo crontab -e` instead of `crontab -e`)? If so, you don't need `sudo`. For cron jobs of normal users, `sudo` would ask for their passwords, and crontab do not input your password automatically.

Comment: just try, if using 'crontab -e' instead of 'sudo crontab -e' , the instance will not restart due to permission denied.

Comment: I mean you don't need `sudo` in the cron job when running root cron jobs. You cron job would become  `01 12 * * * /usr/bin/supervisorctl restart {instance name}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Root cron jobs do not need to specify `sudo` in the script path to run with administrative privilege (root has the top-level privilege).

To add a cron job to list of root's cron jobs, run: `sudo crontab -e`

Your cron tab entry should be modified to:

```
01 12 * * * /usr/bin/supervisorctl restart {instance name}
```

Comment: hi, it seems that method only worked yesterday,  it's weird, the crontab job restart the instance successfully but still not trigger the function inside today.

Comment: Then probably it's another problem

Comment: Does it run correctly if you run the command yourself as root? (Sudo into root, then run the command)

Comment: the cloud service only allow me to run the command like "sudo supervisorctl restart {instance name}", and it works. And most important, every time i used the restart link in the supervisor console, it seems no problem at all! (when i use the crontab to restart, the uptime in the console shows that the instance did restart at that moment, but no function was triggered)

Comment: VERY STUPID FAULT!!!! I have rechecked my source, then i realised that i have set a condition to trigger the function, which is something like 'if int(now_hour) > 12:', i used crontab to restart the script at 12:00, which of course the function would not be triggered. every time i restart on the console was later than 13pm, that's why it would work!!!